# How to get Telegram Bot statistics?

Tags: telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

Does exists any way to get bot's statistics with API or with web interface or with BotFather? Or I must to collect statistics by processing updates from bot API?

ps. Currently I store statistics in Redis by processing updates from bot API, but I wish find better way.

Answer (score 5):

As **aleix** said there is no official support. After several days of research I've found the solutions for all platform bots, **including telegram**:

- [Chatbase.com](https://chatbase.com) from Google
- [botanalytics.co](https://botanalytics.co/) (free + paid)
- [dashbot.io](https://www.dashbot.io/)(free up to 10 M messages)

Comment: Upon trying to set up a bot, it seems Dashbot doesn't have an option to use Telegram.

Answer (score 2):

no, **there is no official support** from Telegram to do that. There are third party analytics like botan, you can get navigate via bot to your bots stats:

- [Botan.io](http://botan.io/) (seems to be abandoned)
- You can see an example here: [analytics tool for your telegram Bot](http://telegramgeeks.com/2015/12/botan-io-analytics-for-telegram-bot/)
- They also have integration to track more data via website: 
  [url-shortening](https://github.com/botanio/sdk#url-shortening)

Answer (score 0):

If it is your bot performance that you worry about and you bot is popular (~300 requests per min), Botfather will monitor the request/response rate and alert you if there is something wrong.

Check the [Status alert section in Bot Intro](https://core.telegram.org/bots#status-alerts).

Answer (score -1):

no actually you cant! But the easiest way for getting statistics about the users is to save the chat_id to database or into simple txt file.

the best way for that is use php mysql function to insert each chat_id into 1 columns then send it to your chat_id ...!